# Template typename

Tags: c++, templates, types, typename

Does the `C++ standard` somehow specify what can a `T` be in the following declaration:

```
template <typename T>
```

I mean, from practical terms of view this can be any particular type, which allows the template to compile *(when the corresponding substitution happens)*.

But what about the **strict definition?**

Comment: `T` can be any type name, i.e. anything that names a type. Types can be anything; fundamentals, arrays, references, unions, enums, classes...

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you're asking. What exactly do you mean by "strict definition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that the data type being used for `T` is compatible and has all the necessary operations that will performed on `T` defined. As far as the C++ standard is concerned any data type can be used in place of `T` there.

Answer (score 2):

As you want the standard, here it is:

C++03, 14.1, Template parameters:

```
A template defines a family of classes or functions.

template-declaration:
    exportopt template < template-parameter-list > declaration
template-parameter-list:
    template-parameter
     template-parameter-list , template-parameter

template-parameter:
    type-parameter
    parameter-declaration
type-parameter:
    class identifieropt
    class identifieropt = type-id
    typename identifieropt
    typename identifieropt = type-id
    template < template-parameter-list > class identifieropt
    template < template-parameter-list > class identifieropt = id-expression

..
```

> A type-parameter defines its identifier to be a type-name (if declared with class or typename) or     template-name (if declared with template) in the scope of the template declaration.
>
> ..
>
> If the use of a template-argument gives rise to an ill-formed construct in the instantiation of a template specialization, the program is ill-formed.

The other things are for default parameters, non-type templates, etc. In other words, the standard does not say *anything* about `T`.

Comment: There's actually a bit more, e.g. on the meaning of `f<int()>();` (14.3)

Comment: Yes, but they are more about ambiguity/behavior, syntax, etc. But thanks, I found one more relevant thing. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict definition, since that would seem to go against the very purpose of templates. `T` is any type that is, for example, passed as an argument to a function with a parameter of type `T`.

You sacrifice the safety of strict type definitions for the code reusability of templates. With that freedom, you need to provide the checks to make sure that `T` is of a reasonable type for the function.

Comment: Nothing is sacrificed. When a template is instantiated with a particular type it is compiled as normal (ie with strict type checking).

Comment: Well you give up the biggest advantage of strict types when writing the code, which is that the compiler will make sure that anything passed in is of the given type. With templates you need to be prepared for a string or an int or whatever.

Comment: This is true for template methods (not for template classes) in that you can pass anything. But not true that you give up anything. For each method that is called with a type the compiler generates and compiles the method specifically for that class. Thus it is strictly type checked. If the type does not work you get a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

boost has a helpful template, enable_if that lets you enable templates for only particular types.